# Get-FileHash on vmdk file using PowerCLI

Tags: powershell, vmware, vsphere, powercli

I am new to PowerCLI, and I am having little difficulties.
I need to calculate a hash on a vmdk file (around 50GB), I want to do this using PowerCLI, which has the following command:

```
Get-FileHash <filepath> -Algorithm MD5
```

I am connecting to my vsphare with the following command:

```
Connect-VIServer -Server servername -User user -Password pass

Get-Template -Name tempName | Get-HardDisk
```

gives me the following

```
CapacityGB      Persistence                                                    Filename
----------      -----------                                                    --------
60.000          Persistent                          [CCT_VMs_22] tempName/tempName.vmdk
```

but I cant use the Get-FileHash on the above.

any ideas what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Get-filehash is a native powershell command and not part of the VMware PowerCLI module, you'd need to copy the vmdk file to a windows box somewhere before you can use Get-FileHash.

You could use PSCP to copy the file locally then do Get-FileHash.

PowerCLI also has a native way to do file copies to your local machine here:

https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2001041

Comment: a copy will take too much time, is there any way to do it locally?

Comment: Yep, use md5sum <filename> from the vSphere server CLI, access using putty or another tool, you'll have to turn SSL on and start the SSL service to do that.